# Method invocation on NULL works fine - Expecting NPE

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am able to invoke the greet method on `null`, Here i am expecting `NPE` as we can not invoke method on `null` from  language specification `JLS-15.12`.

But here i am getting `hello world`

```
    public class Test{
    public static void greet() {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ((Test) null).greet();
    }
}
```

Can some help me why I am getting `hello world` instead of `NPE`

Comment: It's a `static` method so you are not calling on `null` as the reference is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler replaces your call with a *static invocation*.
If you inspect your bytecode using `javap -v className`, you will see it.

```
stack=0, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: invokestatic  #31                 // Method greet:()V
         3: return
```

The compiler understands that you are needlessly using a complex way to call your method and reduces it to a basic static call. Static methods are meant to be called *in a static context* and not in an *instance context*, any good IDE will ask you to change your existing code.

Even if you do `new Sample().greet();`, the compiler does the same optimization.

Comment: It may be worth expanding on your last statement because anyone calling a static method on an instance might not immediately understand why that's "needlessly complex". Otherwise, very nice answer.